# Virtual IP is accessible from only one server in High-Availability

Tags: high-availability, ubuntu-18.04

I have configured High-Availability setup in the Ubuntu server and I have one virtual IP which going to access both servers, but when I'm trying to access that IP address is only working from only one server, if I'm trying to access that HA setup from somewhere else its connecting. Please help me to fix that issue.
Server -1 172.16.119.165
Server -2 172.16.119.183
Virtual IP - 172.16.119.172
Subnet Mask - 255.255.224.0

When I'm trying to access fro server one its connecting properly but When I'm trying to access from somewhere else for example from server two it's showing 'no route to host'. I have enabled all required port in shorewall.

Comment: Please provide some information about your network configuration. Currently we can't even guess.

Comment: Server-1 - 172.16.119.165    Server-2 - 172.16.119.183       Virtual-IP - 172.16.119.172    Subnet Mask - 255.255.224.0

Comment: Please edit additional information into your question. It would also helpful to see the actual error messages you encounter when you determine what is "not working".